# Parse and verify a WS Trust XML Token

Tags: .net, saml, adfs, ws-federation, ws-trust

I have a webservice written in c#/.NET that redirects unauthenticated users to a WS Federation identity provider, which then redirects back to my webservice with a SAML token which has the roles of that user. This is as per the passive WS federation specification - http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/federation/v1.2/os/ws-federation-1.2-spec-os.html#_Toc223175008

Having got this, I get a request which has the wresult set to be the token. In my code I've got a **string** 
wresult which is the string for the xml document. What I know is the realm im on, the thumbprint of the identity provider, the wctx (if it was sent).

The security token is a standard WS-Trust token described here:
http://specs.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/WS-Trust.pdf

What I want to get is the SecurityToken and eventually the IPrincipal for that user just from that **string** which is the XML document/security token.

An example of the string would be (with a few things obfuscated).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">
  <t:Lifetime>
    <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-09-14T13:40:25.164Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-09-14T14:40:25.164Z</wsu:Expires>
  </t:Lifetime>
  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsa:EndpointReference xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:Address>https://localhost:44366/</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:EndpointReference>
  </wsp:AppliesTo>
  <t:RequestedSecurityToken>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" AssertionID="_e1580903-02ac-453d-a157-ae27c8614cc9" Issuer="http://adfs.ORGANISATION.com/adfs/services/trust" IssueInstant="2018-09-14T13:40:25.164Z">
      <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-09-14T13:40:25.164Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-09-14T14:40:25.164Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
          <saml:Audience>https://localhost:44366/</saml:Audience>
        </saml:AudienceRestrictionCondition>
      </saml:Conditions>
      <saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Subject>
          <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
          </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="emailaddress" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>person@stuff.com</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="givenname" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>Jeff</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="surname" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>Mandelson</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="windowsaccountname" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>jeff.mandelson</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="role" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>Stuff\Domain Users</saml:AttributeValue>
          <saml:AttributeValue>Stuff\DevTeam</saml:AttributeValue>
          <saml:AttributeValue>Stuff\RDS-MSSQLDEV-RW</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="upn" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>stuff@local.com</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
        <saml:Attribute AttributeName="name" AttributeNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims">
          <saml:AttributeValue>Jeff Mandelson</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
      </saml:AttributeStatement>
      <saml:AuthenticationStatement AuthenticationMethod="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport" AuthenticationInstant="2018-09-14T11:59:16.147Z">
        <saml:Subject>
          <saml:SubjectConfirmation>
            <saml:ConfirmationMethod>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:cm:bearer</saml:ConfirmationMethod>
          </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
      </saml:AuthenticationStatement>
      <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
          <ds:Reference URI="#_e1580903-02ac-453d-a157-ae27c8614cc9">
            <ds:Transforms>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
              <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>a_digest_value_removed</ds:DigestValue>
          </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>signature</ds:SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>certificate</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
      </ds:Signature>
    </saml:Assertion>
  </t:RequestedSecurityToken>
  <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>
  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>
  <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>
</t:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
```

I've tried using the inbuilt methods such as 
WSFederationAuthenticationModule, however, this seems to have problems unless you're using System.Web.Request. An inbuilt .NET/C# function would be preferable!

Comment: You want this in C#/.NET?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't make that very clear

Comment: The WSFam can still be used, even without the `Request`.

Comment: could you explain how? I've tried using the WSFAM and failed. It keeps giving me an "object reference is not defined" exception.... I've ended up using the XML Schemas to parse the SAML token, which is almost going well, except the microsoft ws security claims schema have been taken down.

Comment: I think you don't need schemas but a couple of XPath expressions to retrieve the username (or other claims you need) and a couple of lines to verify the signature. Note that the token is a regular XMLDsig signed XML, a generic validation code will work. Don't have the compiler at hand during the weekend but if you comment this and I catch it tomorrow, I will try to write an answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I've managed to use xsd to turn the token into a reasonably nice c# class (it has the claims, the username, the signature, etc). Not sure entirely on how the signature works - what exactly is being signed? The RequestedSecurityToken minus the signature? Is the whole document being signed? The other problem I have is even if I verify this token, how do I know exactly what kind of SAML token ADFS will use?

Comment: This is why @WiktorZychla I assume using the WSFAM is the ideal solution. I've also looked at using identitymodel.tokens which has a SAMLSecurityToken parses which does the validation as well.

Comment: Wrote the answer, I hope it suits you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to think of the token as it was a regular XMLDsig signed XML - the assertion node is signed and the signature's reference points back to it. The code is rather simple, what's interesting however is that the `SignedXml` class has to be inherited to have the signature validator that follows the `AssertionID` attribute (the default convention is that the signed node's id attribute is called just `ID` and the default validator just won't find the node that has the id attribute called differently).

```
public class SamlSignedXml : SignedXml
{
    public SamlSignedXml(XmlElement e) : base(e) { }

    public override XmlElement GetIdElement(XmlDocument document, string idValue)
    {
        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);
        mgr.AddNamespace("trust", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512");
        mgr.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
        mgr.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion");

        XmlElement assertionNode = 
               (XmlElement)document.SelectSingleNode("//trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection/trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/"+
                                                     "trust:RequestedSecurityToken/saml:Assertion", mgr);

        if (assertionNode.Attributes["AssertionID"] != null &&
            string.Equals(assertionNode.Attributes["AssertionID"].Value, idValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
            )
            return assertionNode;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that the XPath assumes the token has the `RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection` in the root, make sure your tokens follow this convention (in case of a single token, the collection node can be missing and the token's root could be just `RequestSecurityTokenResponse`, update the code accordingly).

The validation code is then

```
// token is the string representation of the SAML1 token
// expectedCertThumb is the expected certificate's thumbprint
protected bool ValidateToken( string token, string expectedCertThumb, out string userName )
{
 userName = string.Empty;

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token)) return false;

 var xd = new XmlDocument();
 xd.PreserveWhitespace = true;
 xd.LoadXml(token);

 XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xd.NameTable);
 mgr.AddNamespace("trust", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512");
 mgr.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
 mgr.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion");

 // assertion
 XmlElement assertionNode = (XmlElement)xd.SelectSingleNode("//trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection/trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/trust:RequestedSecurityToken/saml:Assertion", mgr);

 // signature
 XmlElement signatureNode = (XmlElement)xd.GetElementsByTagName("Signature")[0];

 var signedXml = new SamlSignedXml( assertionNode );
 signedXml.LoadXml(signatureNode);

 X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
 foreach (KeyInfoClause clause in signedXml.KeyInfo)
 {
  if (clause is KeyInfoX509Data)
  {
   if (((KeyInfoX509Data)clause).Certificates.Count > 0)
   {
    certificate =
    (X509Certificate2)((KeyInfoX509Data)clause).Certificates[0];
   }
  }
 }

 // cert node missing
 if (certificate == null) return false;

 // check the signature and return the result.
 var signatureValidationResult = signedXml.CheckSignature(certificate, true);

 if (signatureValidationResult == false) return false;

 // validate cert thumb
 if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( expectedCertThumb ) )
 {
  if ( !string.Equals( expectedCertThumb, certificate.Thumbprint ) )
   return false;
 }

 // retrieve username

 // expires = 
 var expNode = xd.SelectSingleNode("//trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection/trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/trust:Lifetime/wsu:Expires", mgr );

 DateTime expireDate;

 if (!DateTime.TryParse(expNode.InnerText, out expireDate)) return false; // wrong date

 if (DateTime.UtcNow > expireDate) return false; // token too old

 // claims
 var claimNodes =                 
   xd.SelectNodes("//trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection/trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse/trust:RequestedSecurityToken/"+
                  "saml:Assertion/saml:AttributeStatement/saml:Attribute", mgr );
 foreach ( XmlNode claimNode in claimNodes )
 {
  if ( claimNode.Attributes["AttributeName"] != null && 
              claimNode.Attributes["AttributeNamespace"] != null &&
       string.Equals( claimNode.Attributes["AttributeName"].Value, "name", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) &&   
                     string.Equals( claimNode.Attributes["AttributeNamespace"].Value, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ) &&
         claimNode.ChildNodes.Count == 1 
      )
  {
   userName = claimNode.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
   return true;
  }
 }

 return false;
}
```

With some minor tweaks, you should be able to do what you want.

BTW. Most of the answer is copied from my blog entry

https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2018/09/parsing-saml-11-ws-federation-tokens.html

that documents the approach we are using internally in one of our apps. I planned to
make this entry for some time and your question was just a trigger I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the IdentityModel SamlTokenVerifier and Parser:

```
public static bool AuthenticateXmlToken(String wresult)
        {


            String pstrXML = wresult;

            // write it down 
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\USER\\Downloads\\asdf4.xml", wresult);

            // extract the SAML Assertion
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(pstrXML));
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Assertion", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion");

            // saml requirements 
            SamlSecurityTokenRequirement pRequirements = new SamlSecurityTokenRequirement();
            pRequirements.CertificateValidator = new CertificateValidator();

            SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration pConfig = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
            pConfig.AudienceRestriction = new AudienceRestriction(AudienceUriMode.Never);
            pConfig.IssuerNameRegistry = new IssuerNames();

            //pRequirements.ValidateAudienceRestriction()
            SamlSecurityTokenHandler pHandler = new SamlSecurityTokenHandler(pRequirements);
            pHandler.Configuration = pConfig;


            SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlerCollection = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
            SamlSecurityToken token = (SamlSecurityToken)pHandler.ReadToken(reader.ReadSubtree());

            ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> pClaims = pHandler.ValidateToken(token);

            return pClaims.Count > 0;
        }


        public class IssuerNames : IssuerNameRegistry
        {
            public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken)
            {

                return "Issuer";
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }


        public class CertificateValidator : X509CertificateValidator
        {
            public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
            {
                if (certificate == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("certificate is null");
                }

                if (certificate.Thumbprint.ToLower() != "mythumprint")
                {
                    throw new Exception("X509 certficate is signed with the wrong public key!");
                }
            }
        }
```